# $\||u|\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \| u \|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}$ holds for even if $s$ is not an integer?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

Let $u: \mathbb R^n \ni x\mapsto u(x) \in \mathbb C.$
I would like to know that the inequality

$$
\||u|\|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \| u \|_{\dot H^s(\mathbb R^n)}
$$
or
$$
\||u|\|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)} \le C \| u \|_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}
$$

for any $s\ge 0$ with some positive constant $C$ . Actually, I think I can prove the inequality holds for $s=0,1,2,\cdots$, However, I cannot sure the inequality holds even if $s$ is not an integer. Here $|\cdot |$ is the absolute value notation and $\dot H^s$, $H^s$ are the homogeneous Sobolev space, Sobolev space of order $s$ respectively.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't think $|f|$ is generally in the Sobolev space $H^s$ for $s \ge 2$.  Maybe not even for $s > 1$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge I found some related lemma such as Lemma 3.4 on page 13 in this paper(http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/AIHPA/AIHPA_1994__60_2/AIHPA_1994__60_2_211_0/AIHPA_1994__60_2_211_0.pdf). When I set $f(z) = |z|$ then I think the Lemma works for this case. Would you please confirm this?

Comment: Among the assumptions of that lemma is that $f$ is $C^1$, which is not true for $f(z)=|z|$, and that $f'(0)=0$, which is not true for $f(z)=z$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thanks. I really appreciate to your comment. Then can I use the above lemma for the case something like $f(z) = |z|^{1/2} z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Sobolev spaces, I like to think about the case $n=1$ first, since there, the Sobolev functions can be easily characterized. Using this, we will show that the claim is false for $s \geq 2$.

To this end, take $f \in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ with $f(x) = x$ for $|x| < 1$. Then $|f(x)| = |x|$ for $|x| < 1$ and hence the weak derivative of $|f|$ is given by
$$
g(x) := \frac{d}{dx} |f(x)| = \begin{cases}1 & x > 0 \\ -1 & x < 0\end{cases}
$$
for $|x| < 1$.

Note that $g$ does not have a continuous representative. In particular, $g \notin H^1$, whence $|f| \notin H^s$ (otherwise, we would have $g \in H^{s-1} \subset H^1$), although $f \in C_c^\infty \subset H^s$ for every $s > 0$.

For $s = 1$, it is a classical result about Sobolev spaces that your claim is true (iirc) and for $s=0$ we have $H^s = L^2$, so that the claim also holds. A moment ago, I was tempted to claim that this implies your claim for $0 \leq s \leq 1$ by interpolation, but since the map $f \mapsto |f|$ is nonlinear, this will not work that easily...

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate to your kind answer. Would you let me know what happens for the case $1<s<2$? I could easily show that the inequality holds for $s=1$ as in my question lists.

Comment: @Kumarta: In general, I am not sure. But Theorem 8.2 here (http://www.instmath.rwth-aachen.de/~heiko/lehre/varisemWS11-12/hitchikers_guide_fractional_sobolev_4_2011.pdf) shows that functions in $H^s$ are continuous for $2s > n$. Now, in the example above, this holds as soon as $s > 1/2$. Thus, we have $g \notin H^{s}$ for all $s > 1/2$ which implies $|f| \notin H^{t}$ for all $t > 3/2$. Hence, the claim is false at least for $s > 3/2$ and $n=1$.